# Postfix Error 451 4.3.5 Server configuration error; after Server Migration

Tags: debian, postfix-mta

today I tried to migrate my old Server to new VM-Hardware. The server is based on Debian 10 and uses Postfix, Dovecot in combination with rspamd. The used UI is Open-Xchange. After I transferred a Snapshot to the new Server I changed the IP-Address and updated the packages. Everything works fine expect postfix. When I try to send an External Mail or receive an external mail Postfix block the Mail and returns an 451 4.3.5 Server configuration error. I updated the IP-Address in the main.cf but the error is still the same. Anyone has an idea? I greped threw the system and cant find any other places where my old ip-address is configured in the system.
Heres the Log from an Mail-Transfer:

```
Out: 220 mail.drei.wtf ESMTP Postfix
  In:   EHLO m193-63.mailgun.net
  Out: 250-mail.drei.wtf
  Out: 250-PIPELINING
  Out: 250-SIZE 52428800
  Out: 250-ETRN
  Out: 250-STARTTLS
  Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
  Out: 250-8BITMIME
  Out: 250-DSN
  Out: 250 CHUNKING
  In:   STARTTLS
  Out: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
  In:   EHLO m193-63.mailgun.net
  Out: 250-mail.drei.wtf
  Out: 250-PIPELINING
  Out: 250-SIZE 52428800
  Out: 250-ETRN
  Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
  Out: 250-8BITMIME
  Out: 250-DSN
  Out: 250 CHUNKING
  In:   MAIL FROM:<postmaster@cio46406.ottowilde.com>  BODY=8BITMIME
  Out: 250 2.1.0 Ok
  In:   RCPT TO:<xxxxx>
  Out: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration error
  In:   QUIT
  Out: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Heres the content of the mail.log:

```
Dec 25 13:57:31 mail postfix/smtpd[2449]: connect from m193-63.mailgun.net[161.38.193.63]
Dec 25 13:57:32 mail postfix/smtpd[2449]: warning: unknown smtpd restriction: "permit_mynetwoks"
Dec 25 13:57:32 mail postfix/smtpd[2449]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from m193-63.mailgun.net[161.38.193.63]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration error; from=<postmaster@cio46406.ottowilde.com> to=<xxxxx> proto=ESMTP helo=<m193-63.mailgun.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

found my problem. Seemed that i accidentially removed an 'r' in the configuration file while using vi. The warning unknown smtpd restriction: "permit_mynetw**ok**s" was causing the error.